# ListView: disabling clicking/focus

Tags: java, android

I added a header view to my ListView and it's working quite well, the problem I'm having right now is that I need to remove the default clicking/focus effect when I click the header.

Apart from that, is it possible to also remove the click/focus effect to some items when they are "disabled" options?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Of course you can do this! For header or footer views you can just call [`addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) or [`addFooterView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) respectively with `isSelectable == false`.

For regular list items you may just return `false` for the [`boolean isEnabled (int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) method. :-)

Comment: see, that's the thing! in code I don't know when to call isEnabled :( so it kinda drove me nuts... return false in the onClickListener ?

Comment: You do use an adapter, don't you? Hopefully a ListAdapter or a BaseAdapter? If so: Just override the isEnabled() method and return false there for items you don't want to get selected. See List5.java in the API demos http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html for reference.

Comment: Cheers on that mate, Yes I'm using an adapter, I'll take a look on those docs, time to get rid of this headache =/ Thing is I'm using the arrayAdapter, didn't expect to extend the baseAdapter. Thought there was another way to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by just setting the onClickHandler for the header view to null...worked for me.

Comment: This is the best answer i found in this topic so far. I can't use [`addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29), because it removes the last divider on some devices...

Comment: Just to be clear, It's `onClickListener` not `onClickHandler`.