# Adding an OnItemClickListener onto a header in a ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, header, listener

I am trying to add an on click listener to a header in a listview. I can access the elements in the listview fine, but I cannot get access (nor even add a listener) onto the actual header. The reason for this is I would like my list to give a summary of the items in other lists, and if you click on a header it will direct to another screen that shows the full list. I thought maybe the index passed into the overridden onItemClick would give it as an index of 0 (being the first item in the list) but 0 is never passed in as an index; 1 is the lowest thing passed in and it is the first item in the list under the header. Here's what I mean:

```
public void onItemClick( final AdapterView<?> parent, final View item, 
                               final int index, final long id) {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText( this, "CLICKED ON HEADER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText( this, "Clicked on 1st item in list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ...
```

I also thought maybe I could add an icon to the header and add an on-click listener to the icon, but I keep getting a null-pointer:

```
    favorites_list_view = (ListView) findViewById ( R.id.main_favorite_view );
    FavoritesAdapter adapter = new FavoritesAdapter( (Context)this, favoriteData );

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate( 
                                          R.layout.list_header_with_icon, null );
    TextView headerTitle = (TextView)header.findViewById( R.id.main_header_text );
    headerTitle.setText( "Top Favorites" );
    headerIcon = (ImageButton)findViewById( R.id.main_header_icon );
    headerIcon.setOnClickListener( (OnClickListener)this );
    favorites_list_view.addHeaderView( header );

    favorites_list_view.setAdapter( adapter );
    favorites_list_view.setOnItemClickListener( (OnItemClickListener)this );
```

It doesn't work even if I move the setting of the header listener later. Any ideas?

Comment: check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279655/listview-disabling-clicking-focus